# What are the fastest missions for restoring the thieves guild?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I've been wondering what the fastest missions are for restoring the thieves guild? It just seems that they just take too long. Are there certain missions that only take about 5 minutes?

Comment: are you referring to after you have retrieved the eyes of the Falmer?

Comment: yes ive alredy gone through the main story line

Comment: I'm pretty sure you have to do a certain amount (I think 5?) of each type of mission, in each main hold, to complete the quest.

Comment: thx im glad theres an end to them

Comment: There's no end to them technically, you just unlock stuff for the Thieves Guild, as well as leverage in that hold after completing a certain amount.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To answer your question properly and completely:

This quest requires you to complete "Small jobs" given to you by Delvin and Vex, to restore the wealth and power of the Thieves guild.

To complete this quest properly, you will need to complete 5 of each of the 6 types of job, in each of the 4 main holds.

To explain further: 'The fishing job', assigned by Delvin, must be completed 5 times in Whiterun, then you will be given a Special side quest by Delvin, marking the jobs 'completion'. Rounding the total amount of times you need to complete a 'Fishing job" 24 times.

So in total, there are 144 missions you will need to complete, to finish this quest.

Comment: That's a *lot* of "fishing".

Comment: This raises a small question. Besides the achievement, is it actually worth completing it all?

Comment: @Sharain Umm, not really. You get some nice armour, and there is a chest in the thieves guild that gets re-filled with gold and jewels every now and again, but other than that, just the sexy sexy 'pop' as the achievement goes :)

Comment: IMO, a lot of people actually stop the Thieves Guild questline about halfway through, when they get the skeleton key. Unbreakable lockpick? Yes please! There is a perk about 3/4 of the way through the lockpicking skill tree that does the same thing, but this is far easier to obtain.

Comment: The wording 'complete 5 of each of the 6 types of job' should be cleared up. I know you refine it later on again but it should just be 'complete 5 jobs from Vex or Delvin for a single city to open up the special job in that city' or the like.